# SVG spot color and cut lines

Tags: php, pdf, svg

I am developing some software that takes an SVG and inserts it into a PDF using [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/). The PDF will then get sent to a Roland printer that has the ability to cut. I would like to know how I define a spot colour in the SVG to tell the printer where to cut.

The name of the spot color is `CutContour`. How would I tell a path in the SVG to use this color?

The SVG is ready made and does not need to be generated.

Sorry for the uncertainty but I don't really know where to start. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CutContour is not a predefined color - in theory you can assign to it any color, used in SVG.

In order to achieve that, your PDF generating app/lib should be able to output a separation colorspace, like the following.

```
8 0 obj
[/Separation/CutContour/DeviceRGB<</C0[1.0 1.0 1.0]/C1[0.254898 0.498032 1.0]/Domain[0 1]/FunctionType 2/N 1.0/Range[0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0]>>]
endobj
```

I did not dig too deep into details, but in my test sample /C1 value matches RGB, I defined as a CutContour

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understand that I have to some how create a colorspace. However, your answer doesn't look like SVG code?

Comment: Right. It is PDF code. If I understand you correctly, your target file format is PDF (to be sent to the printer). With the PDF colorspace definition code you should be able to select one of the colors used in SVG as CutContour. I have no idea if TCPDF can do that. We could add the feature to our product [link](http://pd4ml.com/cookbook/svg_to_pdf_conversion.htm), but unfortunately we have no cutting printer to experiment with.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean now. And yes I can add a colourspace to the PDF. Thanks :)

Comment: HI, i am using PNG image to create pdf file using TCPDF from my Web Application . I already added CutContour line in PNG image and as per your opinion i added the Separation Color space.  But no use . Can you suggest any solution? .In my case i am using CMYK for image creation and Spot color name as "CutContour"  CMYK(0,100,0,0) etc..