# Embedding attributes in SVG elements in PDFs

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, svg

I'm working with a client running a sign-making business who uses proprietary software--[FlexiSIGN-PRO](http://www.thinksai.com/FlexiSIGN-PRO) and [i-Cut](http://www.esko.com/en/Products/Overview/i-cut-suite/overview). I'm working on a custom SVG-based tool that we'll export on the server side and make work with i-Cut, which takes an image and a vector to create a sign with a face on it. i-Cut takes a PDF, so I've been looking at different solutions for exporting from an SVG file to a PDF using node-based solutions (I've tried [PDFKit](http://pdfkit.org/) and [screen capturing with PhantomJS](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Screen-Capture). Up to this point I've got it working where I can export a vector and an image on top of each other into a PDF, which can be opened up in FlexiSIGN/i-Cut.

However, for the client to quickly create signs, it needs to pass in a "DieColor" color name attribute, but this is a little vague and I'm not totally sure what this means in Proprietary Software Land. When a file is imported/exported with the correct attributes, it should look like this in the "color specs" of the FlexiSign program:

[image]

With my PDFs, that box is missing attributes (although the magenta fill color I'm passing in is working):

[image]

So the question is, how can I export whatever attribute this might be into PDF format? It has to be possible to embed some kind of metadata, but I'm not familiar with the PDF format or how to interact with it, or what libraries will do the job. Is there a better-supported PHP library I could use? I'm also looking into the possibility of using .eps, since apparently i-Cut can use that.

I also recently found this link: [SVG spot color and cut lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977804/svg-spot-color-and-cut-lines)

That has something to do with declaring a PDF colorspace, but I literally know nothing about how that works--does it have something to do with [SVG ColorProfileElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/color.html#ColorProfileElement)?

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think the answer to this other question might solve your problem also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977804/svg-spot-color-and-cut-lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, SVG current standard doesn't support spot color declaration and you'll need customized and/or expensive SVG > PDF conversion tool to convert named SVG color to spot color in PDF. If the only problem with your choice of tools and PDFs produced is they don't have spot color, you can post-process PDFs. Assuming RGB magenta is not used for anything else,

```
$ perl -Mstrict -MCAM::PDF -we '
> sub _n { CAM::PDF::Node->new(@_) }
> @ARGV and my $doc = CAM::PDF->new($ARGV[0]) or die();
> my $r = $doc->getValue($doc->getPage(1)->{Resources});
> $r->{ColorSpace} ||= _n("dictionary", {});
> $doc->getValue($r->{ColorSpace})->{DieLine} = _n("array", [
>     (map {_n("label", $_)} qw(Separation DieLine DeviceCMYK)),
>     _n("reference", $doc->appendObject(undef, 
>         _n("object", _n("dictionary", {
>             FunctionType => _n("number", 2),
>             Domain => _n("array", [map{_n("number", $_)} (0,1)]),
>             C0 => _n("array", [map {_n("number", $_)} (0,0,0,0)]),
>             C1 => _n("array", [map {_n("number", $_)} (0,0.5,1,0.2)]),
>             N => _n("number", 1),
>         })),
>     ,0)),
> ]);
> my $s = $doc->getPageContent(1);
> $s =~ s!(?<=\s)1\s0\s1\srg(?=\s)!/DieLine cs 1 sc!g;
> $doc->setPageContent(1, $s);
> $ARGV[0] =~ s/(.pdf)$/+$1/;
> $doc->cleanoutput($ARGV[0]);
> ' test.pdf
```

the resultant `test+.pdf` should have `DieLine` spot color (more or less orange looking, as in example) in place of 255-0-255 filled shapes.

Comment: Perl is way beyond me (right now) but at a glance this looks awesome. I've figured out an alternate solution to our issue with the client, but I'm accepting this for the work you put in writing it. Thank you!