# PDF and Roland printer specific code

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I must be able to create a PDF with specific "color" codes for Roland printers.

specific code :

- RDG_GLOSS
- RDG_WHITE
- CutContour

so if I understand correctly ;)

the PDF carries a JPG image and in addition information such as rectangles with a specific color code such as "RDG_GLOSS"

I work in PHP and use TCPDF,

I don't know if TCPDF can allow to use specific chromatic spaces,

I can use another library than TCPDF as long as it's PHP, it's the only constraint ^^

examples PDF with AI :
https://mega.nz/#F!OQwzABTA!WTSzA3m3uVE6TDe6uWDN2Q

Information can be useful:
[SVG spot color and cut lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977804/svg-spot-color-and-cut-lines)

the solution may be spot colors :
https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_037/

but I don't know how it works.

Thanks in advance;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spot colours sound like they could be the answer.

```
$pdf->AddSpotColor('My Red Spot Colour', 0, 100, 100, 0);
```

The numbers are CMYK, so you'd need to know what the CMYK values for each printer code are. In my example, 0% cyan + 100% magenta, 100% yellow, 0% black, which gives us red.

Comment: You just gave me an idea.

The printer only pays attention to the name of the color and not to the color itself.

there can be 2 RDG_GLOSS with 2 different colors and this is not a problem.

I'll try this:
$pdf->AddSpotColor('RDG_GLOSS', 0, 100, 100, 0);
$pdf->Text(73, 100, 'RDG_GLOSS');
$pdf->AddSpotColor('RDG_WHITE', 0, 100, 100, 0);
$pdf->Text(73, 100, 'RDG_WHITE');
$pdf->AddSpotColor('CutContour', 0, 100, 100, 0);
$pdf->Text(73, 100, 'CutContour');

Comment: let me know how you get on! :-)

Comment: I confirm, it is the name of the spot that is important for the printer, the color is not used

Comment: glad you sorted everything! :-)

Comment: HI, i am using PNG image to create pdf file using TCPDF from my Web Application . I already added CutContour line in PNG image and i added $pdf->AddSpotColor('CutContour', 0, 100, 0, 0); on my Web app pdf creation file. But no use . Can you suggest any good solution?